# Get data from PHP and process in perl

Tags: php, perl

I have developed a tagger to tag terms of a particular domain. For the tagging purpose I used Perl. The tagger tags abstracts from the literature, I have developed an interface that actually collects the user input. My question is how can I take the data from the interface and pass it to the Perl script as an array and also how to display the output after processing from the Perl script.

I have the necessary tagging script just cannot figure out the above problems.

I got few suggestion using JSON.
So am I suppose to have two different scripts, one php and other the perl that I have.
And what about displaying the processed file automatically

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to use a data marshaling protocol. Two easy possibilities (for PHP and Perl) are:

- JSON output -> JSON input.
- YAML output -> YAML input.

#### JSON

In PHP:

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, json_encode( $struct ));
fclose($fh);
```

In Perl:

```
use File::Slurp qw<read_file>;
use JSON qw<from_json>;

my $struct = from_json( read_file( 'testfile.txt' ));
```

#### [YAML](http://www.yaml.org) (a superset of JSON)

In PHP:

```
yaml_emit_file( "testfile.txt", $struct );
```

In Perl:

```
use File::Slurp qw<read_file>;
use YAML::XS qw<Load>;

my $struct = Load( read_file( 'testfile.txt' ));
```

As well, there's good ol' fashioned XML, but to make that nearly as easy you'd have to use Pear in PHP. But [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aSimple) *could* make it about as easy.

Comment: +1 for JSON.  Both PHP and Perl (with the JSON module) make it ridiculously easy to pass JSON strings around and decode them.

Comment: Can anybody give me a detailed explanation

Comment: @nandini - You've received a detailed explanation.  What about the explanation confuses you?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options.

- You could present the script as a webservice by wrapping it in [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/), [Web::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/Web%3a%3aSimple) or similar and then access that webservice via [cURL](http://php.net/curl/)
- You could use one of the many [command line option parsers](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Getopt) and use PHP's [program execution functions](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you use two different languages like php and java or c or anything else you have to use a standard format language to communicate between them .
to do that you should use websevices that uses the SOAP protocol with xml that is ...
this is my recomandation and I think that is the best solution because its solving many problems and am using it right now to communicate between android application and java EE web application.

Comment: SOAP is unnecessarily complicated for most use cases.